# Smooth structures on connected sums of high dimensional manifolds

Tags: differential-topology

Are there examples of manifolds $M$ of dimension $n\ge 5$ which are nontrivial connected sums, and such that the classification of smooth structures on $M$ is known?

For instance, a connected sum of two (or more) copies of $S^{n-1}\times S^1$? Or Lens spaces? Tori?

A related question is the following: is there a relation between the inertia group of $M_1\#M_2$ and those of $M_1$ and $M_2$?